# Using nest and rollup to create a line chart with a mean in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js, rollup

I'm using trying to use nest and rollup to create a line chart in d3 v4 to display an average score over a number of days. I've exhausted all the tutorials and stackoverflow answers and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the line to display.

I've attached the code below, and would be extremely grateful if anyone could help.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m");

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("csv/formdata.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.scale = +d.scale;
  });

var dataNest = d3.nest()
 .key(function(d) {return d.date;})
 .rollup (function(v) { return {
   averagescale: d3.mean(v, function(d) {return d.scale; })
 }; })
 .entries(data)

 console.log(dataNest)

 // set the ranges
 var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
 var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

 // define the line
 var valueline = d3.line()
     .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
     .y(function(d) { return y(d.averagescale); });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(dataNest, function(d) { return d.averagescale; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data(dataNest)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr('d', function(d) { return valueline (d.averagescale); })

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

csv looks as below

```html
date,grade,scale
10/05,vs,7
10/05,vs,2
11/05,vs,3
11/05,vs,6
12/05,vs,8
12/05,vs,2
13/05,vs,3
13/05,vs,6
```

Comment: Your line function expects two values not one. Can you add the date to the values in the nest?  Having it only be the key is going to mess up the line function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: Since you rolled up.value will hold the `averagescale`.

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataNest, function(d) { return d.averagescale; })]);
```

It should have been:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataNest, function(d) { return d.value.averagescale; })]);
```

Subsequently the line function will also need to be changed:

```
 var valueline = d3.line()
     .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
     .y(function(d) { return y(d.averagescale); });
```

It should be:

```
 var valueline = d3.line()
     .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.key)); })
     .y(function(d) { return y(d.value.averagescale); });
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xl5655jmzly8aBB0JEj7?p=info)

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much for taking the time out to do this. I knew it was something to do with the y and the value line, but just couldn't work it out.